# Событие keypress не срабатывает

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на клавиши происходило определенное событие. Пишу код:

```
 private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("проверка"); // не срабатывает
              moveRight();
          }
          if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("проверка2"); //срабатывает
              moveRight();
          }
      }
```

Для клавиши "Enter" код работает, а для клавиши "A" не срабатывает. Подскажите, где ошибка. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таком виде Ваш код заработает

```
  private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.KeyChar == 'a') //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      {
          MessageBox.Show("проверка"); //срабатывает
          moveRight();
      }
      if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("проверка2"); //срабатывает
          moveRight();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Благодарю, всё верно.